# proj4 cookbook?

Tags: proj

Is there a proj4 "cookbook"? I discovered proj4 from @MerseyViking 
excellent answer to: [Create Mercator map with arbitrary center/orientation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29101/) but 
most of the documentation appears to be fairly high level.

EDIT: Details on what I'm trying to do:

- Rotate the globe so that any point I choose is at 0,0 (where the 
  prime meridian crosses the equator) or the North Pole or the South 
  Pole, my choice.
- Apply any projection with any "zoomlevel" I choose to the result.
- "Zoomlevel" meaning that the projection includes only points close 
  to the point I chose earlier.

The linked question shows me how to do this for the Mercator 
projection. How to generalize?

I realize I could write code to do 3D rigid rotations (for step 1 
above), but can proj/cs2cs do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, most people just use it via something like [Proj4JS](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/). The nearest I can find is [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/ProjAPI) page, and [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms) page has a brief description of the most common parameters. But really all you can do with it is set up two projections, and transform 3D points from one to another, so there's not much to know!